# Background transparent for no reason

Tags: html, css, svg, background, transparent

I'm currently working on my new website. [www.sgdesign.nl](http://www.sgdesign.nl/index) (this will change when finished)

I'm having a very odd problem. The background of my logo is transparent in google Chrome, yet i don't understand why. I'm using a .svg file as logo because it's lighter and scales with size without quality loss.

-HTML-

```
<div id="logo_background">
<div id="logo"></div>
</div>
```

-CSS-

```
#logo_background {
    float:none;
    padding-left:5px;
    opacity:1;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:-10px;
    width:142px;
    height:160px;
    background-color:White;
    border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
}

#logo {
    margin:auto;
    width:120px;
    height:150px;
    background-image:url(../images/SG_Design_Logo.svg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:150px;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

I have no idea why the top portion of the logo background is transparent in google Chrome. I look forward to suggestions and fixes

-Edit- 
I have changed the background color to Green to highlight the problem better.

Comment: well because in your svg code there is white background..in your svg <rect y="1" fill="#FFFFFF" width="595.3" height="594.3"> change this FFFFFF to FF0000 and your issue will be resolved..don't forget to remove the white background from logo_background class too..

Comment: I thought you are talking that why you are getting white background?is that mean transparent according to you?

Comment: I do not want transparency, it's transparent in google chrome, not in the other browsers. I have editted the post, forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is ***not*** transparent.

The background rectangle has a white fill

```
<rect y="1" fill="#FFFFFF" width="595.3" height="594.3"/>
```

You would need to change this to

```
<rect y="1" fill=none" width="595.3" height="594.3"/>
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
svg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 595.3" enable-background="new 0 0 595.3 595.3" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect y="1" fill="none" width="595.3" height="594.3" />
  <circle fill="#F7941E" cx="297.8" cy="240.2" r="239.2" />
  <g opacity="0.1">

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="203.675" y1="416.455" x2="422.2705" y2="197.8596" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 57.6481 595.2601)">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#000000" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#58595B" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_6_)" d="M349.6,362.8c-2.5,1.8-5.5,3.2-8.9,4.3c-9.5,0.9-19.2,1.4-29,1.4c-31.7,0-57.1-7.8-76.4-23.3
  l126.1,126.1c94.7-25.9,166.2-108.2,176.1-208.6L400.6,125.8l-17.3,41.7c-6.1-3-20.8-14.2-27-16.3l-58.5-2l-35.9,29l-10.8,16.5
  l-12.4,28.6l14,48.7c2.8,12.1,7.3,22.1,13.5,30.2c11.2,14.4,27.5,21.6,48.9,21.6c10.2,0,20.6-1,31.1-2.9c3.6,2.8,6.4,5.6,8.5,8.5
  c2.8,3.9,4.1,8.3,4.1,13.2C359,351.6,355.8,358.3,349.6,362.8z" />
  </g>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M302.2,224.4c0,4.7,1.1,8.8,3.3,12.3c2.2,3.5,5.7,6.9,10.4,10.2c4.8,3.3,16.1,9.2,33.9,17.7
 c23.6,11.3,39.7,22.6,48.5,33.9c1.1,1.4,2.2,2.9,3.1,4.5v-79.6h-99.2C302.3,223.8,302.2,224.1,302.2,224.4z" />
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M340.7,367.1c3.4-1.1,6.4-2.5,8.9-4.3c6.3-4.5,9.4-11.2,9.4-20c0-4.9-1.4-9.3-4.1-13.2
 c-2.1-2.9-5-5.8-8.5-8.5c-10.5,1.9-20.9,2.9-31.1,2.9c-21.4,0-37.7-7.2-48.9-21.6c-11.2-14.4-16.8-35.3-16.8-62.7
 c0-26.2,7-47.1,20.9-62.6c13.9-15.5,32.4-23.3,55.5-23.3c19.9,0,39,4.6,57.4,13.8l17.8-42.8c-24-10.3-49-15.5-74.9-15.5
 c-41.3,0-73.6,11.4-96.8,34.2s-34.9,54.5-34.9,95.2c0,41.9,10,74,30.1,96.3c20.1,22.4,49.1,33.5,87.2,33.5
 C321.5,368.5,331.2,368,340.7,367.1z" />
  <g>
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M92.9,551.3c0,4.6-1.6,8.2-4.9,10.8c-3.3,2.6-7.9,3.9-13.7,3.9c-5.4,0-10.2-1-14.3-3v-10
  c3.4,1.5,6.3,2.6,8.7,3.2c2.4,0.6,4.5,0.9,6.5,0.9c2.4,0,4.2-0.5,5.4-1.4c1.3-0.9,1.9-2.2,1.9-4c0-1-0.3-1.9-0.8-2.6
  c-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.5-2.4-2.2c-1.1-0.7-3.3-1.9-6.6-3.4c-3.1-1.5-5.4-2.9-7-4.2c-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.9-3.7-4.7c-0.9-1.8-1.4-3.9-1.4-6.2
  c0-4.5,1.5-8,4.6-10.6c3-2.6,7.2-3.8,12.6-3.8c2.6,0,5.1,0.3,7.5,0.9s4.9,1.5,7.5,2.6l-3.5,8.3c-2.7-1.1-4.9-1.9-6.7-2.3
  s-3.5-0.7-5.2-0.7c-2,0-3.6,0.5-4.7,1.4s-1.6,2.2-1.6,3.7c0,0.9,0.2,1.8,0.7,2.5c0.4,0.7,1.1,1.4,2.1,2c1,0.7,3.2,1.8,6.8,3.6
  c4.7,2.3,8,4.5,9.7,6.8C92.1,545.1,92.9,548,92.9,551.3z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M135.5,536.9h20.1v26.3c-3.3,1.1-6.3,1.8-9.2,2.2c-2.9,0.4-5.8,0.6-8.8,0.6c-7.6,0-13.5-2.2-17.5-6.7
  c-4-4.5-6-10.9-6-19.3c0-8.2,2.3-14.5,7-19.1s11.2-6.9,19.5-6.9c5.2,0,10.2,1,15,3.1l-3.6,8.6c-3.7-1.8-7.5-2.8-11.5-2.8
  c-4.6,0-8.4,1.6-11.2,4.7c-2.8,3.1-4.2,7.3-4.2,12.6c0,5.5,1.1,9.7,3.4,12.6c2.3,2.9,5.5,4.3,9.8,4.3c2.2,0,4.5-0.2,6.8-0.7v-10.6
  h-9.6L135.5,536.9L135.5,536.9z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M256.5,539.5c0,8.3-2.4,14.7-7.1,19.2c-4.7,4.4-11.6,6.7-20.6,6.7h-14.3v-50.6h15.9
  c8.3,0,14.7,2.2,19.3,6.5C254.2,525.6,256.5,531.7,256.5,539.5z M245.3,539.8c0-10.9-4.8-16.3-14.4-16.3h-5.7v33h4.6
  C240.1,556.5,245.3,550.9,245.3,539.8z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M310.3,565.3h-29.2v-50.6h29.2v8.8h-18.4v11.1H309v8.8h-17.1v13.1h18.4V565.3z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M365,551.3c0,4.6-1.6,8.2-4.9,10.8c-3.3,2.6-7.9,3.9-13.7,3.9c-5.4,0-10.2-1-14.3-3v-10
  c3.4,1.5,6.3,2.6,8.7,3.2c2.4,0.6,4.5,0.9,6.5,0.9c2.4,0,4.2-0.5,5.4-1.4c1.3-0.9,1.9-2.2,1.9-4c0-1-0.3-1.9-0.8-2.6
  c-0.6-0.8-1.4-1.5-2.4-2.2c-1.1-0.7-3.3-1.9-6.6-3.4c-3.1-1.5-5.4-2.9-7-4.2c-1.6-1.3-2.8-2.9-3.7-4.7c-0.9-1.8-1.4-3.9-1.4-6.2
  c0-4.5,1.5-8,4.6-10.6c3-2.6,7.2-3.8,12.6-3.8c2.6,0,5.1,0.3,7.5,0.9c2.4,0.6,4.9,1.5,7.5,2.6l-3.5,8.3c-2.7-1.1-4.9-1.9-6.7-2.3
  c-1.8-0.4-3.5-0.7-5.2-0.7c-2,0-3.6,0.5-4.7,1.4s-1.6,2.2-1.6,3.7c0,0.9,0.2,1.8,0.7,2.5c0.5,0.7,1.1,1.4,2.1,2
  c1,0.7,3.2,1.8,6.8,3.6c4.7,2.3,8,4.5,9.7,6.8S365,548,365,551.3z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M388.3,565.3v-50.6H399v50.6H388.3z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M445.2,536.9h20.1v26.3c-3.3,1.1-6.3,1.8-9.2,2.2c-2.9,0.4-5.8,0.6-8.8,0.6c-7.6,0-13.5-2.2-17.5-6.7
  c-4-4.5-6-10.9-6-19.3c0-8.2,2.3-14.5,7-19.1s11.2-6.9,19.5-6.9c5.2,0,10.2,1,15,3.1l-3.6,8.6c-3.7-1.8-7.5-2.8-11.5-2.8
  c-4.6,0-8.4,1.6-11.2,4.7c-2.8,3.1-4.2,7.3-4.2,12.6c0,5.5,1.1,9.7,3.4,12.6c2.3,2.9,5.5,4.3,9.8,4.3c2.2,0,4.5-0.2,6.8-0.7v-10.6
  h-9.6L445.2,536.9L445.2,536.9z" />
    <path fill="#F7941E" d="M536.5,565.3h-13.6l-22-38.3h-0.3c0.4,6.8,0.7,11.6,0.7,14.5v23.8h-9.7v-50.6h13.5l22,37.9h0.2
  c-0.3-6.6-0.5-11.2-0.5-14v-24h9.7L536.5,565.3L536.5,565.3z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Note...the logo will now show the logo_background color below...which is currently white. If you don't want that you should remove it.

Comment: So, to clear this up, i DON'T want a transparent background. Currently it is in 'chrome'. I'm sorry, i should have included the browser.

Comment: The background is *not* transparent in Chrome (at least not in mine)...it's white.

Comment: That's so strange... then maybe it's a local bug.

Comment: It's white because there is white color..i already added that line in my comment..

Comment: It should also be noted that although your logo is essentially square, the width/height you have applied to it *do not match*. You might like to change the width if `#logo` to 150 px...that might be mor ewhat you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Paulie_D has already explained this in a comment, but just to make it clear, the reason is as follows:

Your SVG is square (595.3 x 595.3), but you are putting it in a parent `<div>` that is not square.  It is 120px x 150px.

By default, the browser will scale the SVG down to fit the rectangle while keeping the SVG's original aspect ratio (square).  It will also centre it in the ractangle.  So you will end up with blank (ie transparent) areas at the top and bottom of your rectangular parent `<div>`.

This should happen on all browsers, not just Chrome.

If you want to get rid of the transparent areas, then uou should make your parent `<div>` square as well.  Ie. 120x120 or 150x150.